# Why does Anaconda/JupyterLab not find guidata?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, jupyter-lab

After installing `guiqwt` and `guidata` as suggested on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/guiqwt and https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/guidata, by running the code below in Anaconda prompt,

```
conda install -c conda-forge guiqwt
conda install -c conda-forge guidata
```

JupyterLab still has trouble finding the contents:

[image]

What is missing, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Which environment did you install the packages to? Is the program using that same environment?

Comment: When writing the original question, I ran "conda install -c conda-forge guiqwt" in Anaconda prompt. I just re-ran that line, but this time in JupyterLab (where I gt the error message mentioned in the question), and it output "# All requested packages already installed.". So I guess that JupyterLab (which is launched from Anaconda browser) indeed uses the same environment.